# Matching Objects in JavaScriptObject

Tags: javascript

I have the following `dataset` --> `data1` and `data2`:

```
data = [];

data[0] = [{
    "value": 29,
    "series": 1,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "NY",
     "valueColor": "red"
}, {
    "value": 44,
    "series": 2,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "GY",
    "valueColor": "blue"
}, {
    "value": 10,
    "series": 3,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "HY",
     "valueColor": "orange"
},{
    "value": 0,
    "series": 4,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 5,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "",
    "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 6,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
}]

data[1] = [
    {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 1,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 2,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "",
    "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 3,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
},{
    "value": 16,
    "series": 4,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "RY",
    "valueColor": "yellow"
}, {
    "value": 23,
    "series": 5,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "TY",
    "valueColor": "green"

}, {
    "value": 23,
    "series": 6,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "NY",
    "valueColor": "red"

}]


data[2] = [
    {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 1,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 2,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "",
    "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 3,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
},{
    "value": 16,
    "series": 4,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "RY",
    "valueColor": "yellow"
}, {
    "value": 23,
    "series": 5,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "TY",
    "valueColor": "green"

}, {
    "value": 23,
    "series": 6,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "NY",
    "valueColor": "red"

}]


data2 = [];

data2[0] = [{
    "value": 14,
    "series": 1,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "NY",
     "valueColor": "red"
}, {
    "value": 33,
    "series": 2,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "CY",
    "valueColor": "blue"
}, {
    "value": 16,
    "series": 3,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "KY",
     "valueColor": "orange"
},{
    "value": 0,
    "series": 4,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 5,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "",
    "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 6,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
}]

data2[1] = [
    {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 1,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 2,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "",
    "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 3,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
},{
    "value": 22,
    "series": 4,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "RY",
    "valueColor": "yellow"
}, {
    "value": 21,
    "series": 5,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "TY",
    "valueColor": "green"

}, {
    "value": 13,
    "series": 6,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "SY",
    "valueColor": "red"

}]


data2[2] = [
    {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 1,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 2,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "",
    "valueColor": ""
}, {
    "value": 0,
    "series": 3,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "",
     "valueColor": ""
},{
    "value": 26,
    "series": 4,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "RY",
    "valueColor": "yellow"
}, {
    "value": 8,
    "series": 5,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "TY",
    "valueColor": "green"

}, {
    "value": 33,
    "series": 6,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "NY",
    "valueColor": "red"

}]
```

The following code finds the paired object based on `fname` attribute and assign the same color. It works and functional. Initially it loads the `data`, and when I click a button it loads  the `data2`. However, object color changes, I would like make color consistent.

For example, lets assume that `fname= NY` in data has color red, I want same color where `fname=NY` in `data2`

```
function colorSpectrumm(N) {
    var colorMap = [];
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        var r = getRndColor()
        var g = getRndColor();
        var b = getRndColor();
        colorMap.push("#" + r + g + b);
    }
    return colorMap;
}

function getRndColor() {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var hex = Number(n).toString(16);
    if (hex.length < 2) {
        hex = "0" + hex;
    }
    return hex;
}

//match same fname and assign the same color
function process(data) {
    var map = {};
    colorMap = colorSpectrumm(data.length);
    data.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (!map.hasOwnProperty(item.fname) && item.valueColor != "") {
            map[item.fname] = colorMap[index];
        }
        data[index].valueColor = map[item.fname];
    });

 return data;
}

function dataReduce(data){
   data = data.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
  });

  return data;
}

data = dataReduce(data);
data = process(data);
```

### [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/9m1czjqj/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do

```
function makeSameColorsFrom(data1, data2){
  data2.forEach(function(item, index){
    data2[index].valueColor = findItemInObject(data1, item.fname);
  });
  return data2;
}
function findItemInObject(obj, fname){
  var i = $.grep(obj, function(e){ return e.fname == fname; });
  return i.length ? i[0].valueColor : undefined;
}         

var data2 = makeSameColorsFrom(data, data2);
console.log(data, data2);
```

---

```
function makeSameColorsFrom(data1, data2)
```

This method sets the valueColor attribute of each item in second parameter (data2) and by iterating over the first parameter (data1) and search for items with similar `fname`

```
function findItemInObject(obj, fname)
```

This method takes an object and iterates over it and searches the first item that has same fname as provided

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/pideji/1/edit?js,output**

Comment: Thanks a lot Dhiraj.I am fetching json data per call when I click a button. Therefore, I am losing `data` object when I click on the button to get `data2`.

Comment: I don't completely get it. But from what I understand, how about you store them in different variables globally? Also, why don't you add to the question that piece of code where you are losing data variable ?

Comment: I have marked your answer and upvoted as well. I will try to make it work.

Comment: Ok. But please make sure your question is solved. You see that error because you need jquery to make it work. https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/s7u60n5t/2/

Comment: What if I have more than 2 datasets ? How could I handle it? I am just thinking to make it more generic.

Comment: you have more than 2 datasets and all the datasets have to match only one of the datasets ? For example: data2, data3, data4, data5 have to be altered based on data1 ? Is this what you mean ?

Comment: All possible combinations, not only comparision on `data1`. for example there might a similar objects in `data2` and `data4`.

Comment: yes, I think that is possible too. Can be a bit confusing so i suggest you to give solid test cases.